# Touchpad disabled after folding convertible

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen

I have a convertible Laptop, that is a Laptop with a Touchscreen that can be folded over, so it becomes basically a chubby Tablet.

When folding the device, the keyboard and touchpad disable themselves, which is intended to avoid accidental input during tablet mode. When folding back to regular laptop mode, the keyboard gets properly reactivated again, but the touchpad remains deacivated. I can reactivate it manually in the settings, so this is not a *huge* problem, but it is pretty inconvenient.

I updated all my software via the software updater, problem remains. Any help is welcome, including workarounds like some sort of scipt that reactivates the touchpad after leaving tablet mode (I don't know enough about Ubuntu's internals to write that myself).

Technical Information:

- Laptop Model: Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 15ITL05
- OS: Ubuntu 23.04
- Gnome Version: 44.2
- Windowing System: Wayland